# Oozie Job remains in RUNNING state

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive, sqoop, oozie

I am trying to run simple oozie job on HDP cluster. After executing oozie , job remains in Running state.

Here is my Workflow.xml

```
<workflow-app name="sqoop-to-hive" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
  <start to="sqoop2hive"/>
     <action name="sqoop2hive">
     <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
      <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
      <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
      <command>sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test --table testing --split-by err_dt --hive-import --hive-table testing  -m 1</command>
      <file>hive-site.xml</file>
        <archive>mysql-connector-java.jar</archive>
      </sqoop>
<ok to="end"/>
<error to="kill"/>
</action>
<kill name="kill">
<message>Action failed</message>
</kill>
<end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Following is the log that is getting generated..

```
2015-04-07 14:33:32,792  INFO ActionStartXCommand:543 - SERVER[hadoop-slave1.bigdatacoe.td.teradata.com] USER[hduser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[sqoop-to-hive] JOB[0000004-150407125731126-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000004-150407125731126-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] Start action [0000004-150407125731126-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2015-04-07 14:33:32,792  INFO ActionStartXCommand:543 - SERVER[hadoop-slave1.bigdatacoe.td.teradata.com] USER[hduser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[sqoop-to-hive] JOB[0000004-150407125731126-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000004-150407125731126-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000004-150407125731126-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action status=DONE
2015-04-07 14:33:32,792  INFO ActionStartXCommand:543 - SERVER[hadoop-slave1.bigdatacoe.td.teradata.com] USER[hduser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[sqoop-to-hive] JOB[0000004-150407125731126-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000004-150407125731126-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000004-150407125731126-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action updated in DB!
2015-04-07 14:33:32,842  INFO ActionStartXCommand:543 - SERVER[hadoop-slave1.bigdatacoe.td.teradata.com] USER[hduser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[sqoop-to-hive] JOB[0000004-150407125731126-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000004-150407125731126-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop2hive] Start action [0000004-150407125731126-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop2hive] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
```

**Job Property**

```
nameNode=hdfs://masternode:8020
jobTracker=masternode:8021
oozie.wf.application.path=oozie-sqoop
queueName=default
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.libpath= /user/oozie/share/lib
```

Not sure what is wrong here. Please let me know how should I proceed here?

Comment: I think you neednot put the sqoop in the <command>sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test --table testing --split-by err_dt --hive-import --hive-table testing  -m 1</command> , its should be without sqoop only from import

Comment: Hi, I tried removing sqoop word from command but i am still facing same issue.

Comment: give the complete hdfs url for the workflow location mentioned in this path in the job.properties -- oozie.wf.application.path=oozie-sqoop is

Comment: Hi KS Nidhin , I supplied complete path to oozie-sqoop but still job is not progressing.Same problem i am facing.

Answer (score 1):

i faced similar problem in hortonworks sandbox 
after changing this it worked for me.

nameNode=hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020

jobTracker=sandbox.hortonworks.com:8050
try to give fQDN

Answer (score 0):

check your hadoop version, for 2.0 and above.

```
jobTracker=masternode:8021(remove)

jobTracker=masternode:8032
```

8032 is ResourceManager's default port. jobTracker can refer to either the JobTracker or the ResourceManager based on the Hadoop version in use

and copy all hadoop settings into **oozie/conf/hadoop-conf/** folder. Like core-site.xml, hadoop-policy.xml, hdfs-site.xml, yarn-site.xml.

Comment: Hi,Thanks yanyu. I corrected jobtracker port as i am running it on yarn but still facing same issue...

Comment: do you have all hadoop xml in oozie/conf/hadoop-conf/ folder? like core-site.xml, hadoop-policy.xml, hdfs-site.xml, yarn-site.xml.

Comment: hi Yanyu, initially i forgot to place all hadoop configurations files in oozie/conf/hadoop-conf folder , after realizing that i copied all above mentioned files into hadoop-conf dir but again the same problem i am facing....I searched on internet and found that it may be because of map slot not available as my map-reduce job is not getting launched.Let me know in case if missing more as such configuration here....Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you see your map reduce job after run a job? If there is a new map reduce job created, you can check logs in the machine which run this job, a stdout file will contain some meaningful information. The uri looks like hadoop/hadoop-2.5.0/logs/userlogs/application_1426743803195_10077/container_1426743803195_10077_01_000002/

Comment: It looks like no map reduce is launched. I just checked resource manager UI but i couldnt find any job out there. I believe it is failing somewhere before launching a job.

Comment: If you use mysql, you need put a mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar into hdfs, in a uri like baseFolder/share/lib/sqoop. You already have many jar in share/lib, do you?

Comment: Yes ...In share/lib i have lot of another jar files present along with mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar but again no progress..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74702/discussion-between-yanyu-and-shashi).

Comment: @yanyu did you manage to resolve the problem? If yes, posting the solution as an answer would be helpful, since the chat is closed

Comment: This discuss is too old, I can't remember the detail.